# Unable to use colorbox in ajax results suggest what to do?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am having a page on which jQuery and jQuery colorbox libraries are included. I have some functionality which brings a set of results (links) on this page using ajax. On clicking of links (that come on the fly) i want to open colorbox. Please suggest how could i do it.

Comment: well, its simply saying jQuery.fn.colorbox is undefined.

Comment: Are you sure it work links that are not created by AJAX request? First try that to make sure that the pluggin works.

Comment: which may mean that the colorbox javascript file is not included properly. can you confirm whether the colorbox is available in the client. If you are using firefox + firebug please check the net/script tabs in firebug to check whether the colorbox script is available.

Comment: colorbox is available in the client when i use it on the page actual links it works. But if i use it on the links generated at fly through ajax it doesnt works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use live() method to assign the click handler to dynamically created elements like your links. If you provide some code I could show you how to make it.

```
$('a.yourlinkclass').live('click', function(){
  $.colorbox({href:"html_to_show.html"});
});
```

Comment: On the links i have simply written < a href='void(null);' onclick='callMe()' />   function callMe() { jQuery.fn.colorbox({//params}) ;}

Comment: Did you actually try to do that - $.colorbox({}); I guess if you just want to show the colorbox it is fine, to call the plugin directly. How do you call the colorbox now? Paste some code, please

Answer (score 0):

add a class to the links. For example .lightmeup

then you do:

```
$('.lightmeup').click(function(){
$(this).colorbox(/*values and attributes go here*/)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to rebind your colorbox calls in the callback function once the ajax links have loaded in.

Something like:

```
$.get('ajax_links.php', function(data){
    $('#holder').html(data);
    $('#holder a').colorbox();
});
```